# Python Dictionary Error Dict Attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, runtime-error

I have a little Problem in my Pythoncode. Im trying to give a dictionary from one object to a method of another object with this code: `self.data_object.write_result_csv(self.return_data())`

When I run the program this code works 7 from 8 times. In the last run I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write_result_csv'´
```

I had searched the entire day for the problem now and didn't find anything. Has anybody a hint for me.

Edit: Here is the code for the parts:

return_data method:

```
    def return_data(self):
    """Funktion um die Daten des Trades zurückzugeben"""
    return{'start_value': self.start_value, 'start_date': self.start_date, 'end_value': self.end_value, 'end_date': self.end_date, 'win': self.win}
```

write_result_csv method:

```
 def write_result_csv(self, results):
    with open(self.csv_file, 'a', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([results['start_value'], results['start_date'], results['end_value'], results['end_date'], results['win']])
```

Thanks in advance.

Dixieslicer

Comment: Not enough details to answer your question. Try pasting your code

Comment: There's still not enough information. The important bit is where `data_object` comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message,

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write_result_csv'
```

You are trying to call `<dict>.write_result_csv(<args>)`. That means that in the above code, `self.data_object` is a simple `dict()` instead of the object you intend. Can you check that it is **always** initialized properly?

Comment: I got in the debug-mode again and found my fault. In the object where this object has been generated I had an wrong parameter set, so a dict was given instead of an object. 

Sometimes you don't see the forrest between all the trees, like we say in Germany.

Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!